CLMonitor correct way to upgrade from CLLocationManager
I'm trying to upgrade geolocation functions from CLLocationManager to CLMonitor. The main question is how I supposed to move MonitoredRegions from CLLocationManager to CLMonitor. Since ios17 functions (Start/Stop Monitoring) from CLLocationManager are deprecated so How I should move that conditions if in same time I shouldn't use StopMonitoring to remove it from CLLocationManager.
CLMonitor doesn't have conditions added in CLLocationManager. When I add something to CLMonitor then in CLLocationManager we also see this condition in MonitoredRegions but with auto-generated name (some_generated_chars@identifier)

Deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work, just that there is a new/better way of doing something.  Deprecated capabilities will eventually disappear, but it typically takes years.
It is up to you whether you move to CLMonitor or just keep using CLLocationManager.  If your app targets versions earlier than iOS 17 you can probably just stick with CLLocationManager rather than having multiple code paths.
CLMonitor offers a more modern, closure-based interface compared to the delegate pattern adopted by CLLocationManager.  This is more "Swifty" and it also works with Swift async/await - I am not sure if this has much of an impact as you are, presumably, using Maui based on the question tags.
However, if you did want to change your code to use CLMonitor on iOS 17 you would adopt the following approach

On launch on an iOS 17 device, before you set up CLMonitor, check for a boolean value in User Defaults - Something like geoFenceUpdated.
If it is true, do nothing.
If it is false then create a CLLocationManager, remove all geofences and set geoFenceUpdated to true
Finally, create your CLMonitor and create any required geofences.


Probably I will do something like this but I just believed that apple prepared something else for more elegant migration. When we add some new conditions then every event is fired (for Satisfied/ Unsatisfied) which is wrong when doing the migration. Do you know if there is an easy way to not fire the initial event?
btw. instance of CLLocationManager is still needed for e.g. handling permissions

Yes, you still need cllocationmanager for requesting permissions. You can just create a cllocationmanager without setting its delegate to clear the regions and then you won't get region events from it,  it as I said, unless there is a particular issue you are facing with the delegate approach I wouldn't put much effort into changing

I mean when adding conditions to CLMonitor they are also automatically fired... For now I ignore the first executions from that regions but there could be also some pending event which will be lost in that case... CLMonitor has a method AddCondition where I can set the initial value for State which is great and could be helpful but I don't see any chance to get previous state from that region from CLLocationManager (in CLMonitor that option exists)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423804-requeststate ?

"This method performs the request asynchronously and delivers the results to the location manager’s delegate. You must implement the locationManager(_:didDetermineState:for:) method in the delegate to receive the results." Unfortunatelly I need add a DidDetermineState delegate to receive that information which is too hard to control it and can't be sure if it was called by me or not. In CLMonitor you can get a Record by ID where is a property LastEvent and this is what I would need here

Actually I will try to use it and I will see what happens

Is it working fine after adding DidDetermineState method？

In the end I don't use this. I check LocationManager.MonitoredRegions and compare it with LocationMonitor.MonitoredIdentifiers. If sth is missing I remove from LocationManager and add to CLMonitor. I collect that identifiers during the migration so in MonitorEventHandler I can exclude them to not fire any next functions.
btw. If region was added in CLMonitor then in LocationManager,MonitoredRegions may be listed but with weird name (contains @ char) so I also ignore that id's
